# Speed up own GraphLookup implementation over two collections

Tags: mongodb, performance, tree, materialized-views, graphlookup

I store millions of nodes in two collections. First, larger one, is `trustedNodes` and other one is `pendingNodes`. Each node has UUID **_id** and UUID **parentNodeId** fields alongside with text **content** field. I need to build a rootPath - ordered list of documents from a leaf node to a root one using both trusted and pending nodes preferring trusted over pending ones if its possible (sometimes middle nodes are missing and full path can not be built). (average path depth is like 3; with longest one ~100)

i.e. building path on node with `_id = 5` in these two collections:

```
"trustedNodes": [
{
  "_id": "1",
  "content": "someContent1",
  "parentNodeId": null
},
{
  "_id": "2",
  "content": "someContent2",
  "parentNodeId": "1"
},
{
  "_id": "3",
  "content": "someContent3",
  "parentNodeId": "2"
},
{
  "_id": "5",
  "content": "someContent5",
  "parentNodeId": "4"
},
{
  "_id": "7",
  "content": "someContent7",
  "parentNodeId": "2"
}
]

"pendingNodes": [
{
  "_id": "2",
  "content": "other someContent2",
  "parentNodeId": "1"
},
{
  "_id": "4",
  "content": "pending someContent4",
  "parentNodeId": "3"
}
]
```

Should return following document

```
"_id": "5",
"content": "someContent5",
"pathIsComplete": true,
"rootPath": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "content": "someContent1",
      "parentNodeId": null
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "content": "someContent2",
      "parentNodeId": "1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "3",
      "content": "someContent3",
      "parentNodeId": "2"
    },  
    {
      "_id": "4",
      "content": "pending someContent4",
      "parentNodeId": "3"
    }
]
```

For now it's done in the code by doing up to 2*N requests to the db where N is resulting path length. Some pseudocode:

1. `db.trustedNodes.find( { _id: 5 } )`
2. if none found at  step 1 then `db.pendingNodes.find( { _id: 5 } )`
3. set `foundNode` from find result, if not null - append to result array
4. `db.trustedNodes.find({ _id: $foundNode.parentNodeId })`
5. if none found at step 4 then `db.pendingNodes.find({ _id: $foundNode.parentNodeId })`
6. repeat steps 3-5 until `foundNode` or `foundNode.parentNodeId` is null
7. return resulting array with `pathIsComplete` **true** if `foundNode.parentNodeId` is null

Can this be done faster by using aggregation over indexes or by fewer requests?

Before I tried creating a view with `$unionWith -> $set -> $group` view pipeline then doing `$graphLookup` over it. But it was slow because views can not have indexes. Having on demand materialized view with index didn't work also because I **need strong consistency** and updating this materialized view each time I need to do a graphLookup is also slow.

For now I see only one optimisation that can be made: storing previousy computed trusted paths(trusted paths can not change), but first I wanna explore if there are no more elegant solutions

Comment: _"For now it's done in the code by doing up to 2*N requests to the db where N is resulting path length"_ - Show what you have tried so far (code), or what you have tried in MQL. Also, you should probably have `trustedNodes` and `pendingNodes` together in one collection, with a `trusted: true/false` attribute on each document. Or `trustLevel: "trusted"/"pending"`.

Comment: Another optimisation is to repeatedly use `$graphLookup` to create as many long paths with `trusted` nodes, and then doing limited/one-step paths using `pending` nodes, and then repeating this with `trusted` nodes until you reach the end.

Comment: @aneroid I've provided pseudocode with mongosh queries to avoid using specific language isn't it enough? 
As for using one collection for both node types: if I were to do it then a lot of code base should be rewritten to filter out untrusted nodes so I fear it's not possible in the current scenario.
As for repeated `$graphLookup`s - that would work, but first I need to make sure that cases where paths like `trusted-pending-trusted-pending-...` are rare

Comment: If it is a zebra-like mix of trusted/pending nodes in the path $graphLookup won't work without blending both collections.  I second aneroid's advice - yes there is room for optimisation, and it is only for you to decide on feasibility. Try to merge both collections, profile graphLookup pipeline (it want be instantaneous either) and decide whether benefits worth the efforts of refactoring.  And btw, you don't have strong consistency in MongoDB at all - causal at best.

Comment: as for **own** implementation, e.g. without changing the algorithm and structure you can apply general practices: latency optimisation  - move the application (or part of it) closer to the db networkwise; indices optimisation - ensure all your queries to build the path are covered, then select all details for ids in the path; make sure you have sufficient RAM to keep indices in memory etc.